# Lightning Experience Rollout Specialist Challenge 10

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, trailhead, superbadges

Need some help with one of the superbadges.

I've been trying to complete the LEX Rollout Specialist (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/superbadges/superbadge_lex_rollout) but I keep getting the same error:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
>   The Lightning component named TrailheaDX must open a link 
>   to https://developer.salesforce.com/trailheadx/, must open in a new window 
>   (using the target attribute of ui:outputurl), and must be included in the Sales app.

Now, here's my code

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:card title="TrailheaDX Registration" >
        <ui:outputurl aura:id="TrailheaDX" value="https://developer.salesforce.com/trailheadx/" label="TrailheaDX Registration" target="_blank" />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

The component exists, if I wrap it in a container app it works fine and open in a new tab. I added it to the Sales app Home Page and the utility bar and still get the same error.

I tried the forums, trailblazer community, opening a case with no help.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://noopursfdc.wordpress.com/2017/11/04/salesforce-trailhead-lightning-experience-rollout-specialist-superbage/#_top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this.

I've removed the component from everywhere, deleted the component and recreated it with this code, added it to the Sales App utility bar and it finally worked.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ui:outputurl aura:id="TrailheaDX" value="https://developer.salesforce.com/trailheadx/" label="TrailheaDX Registration" target="_blank" />
</aura:component>
```

Comment: https://noopursfdc.wordpress.com/2017/11/04/salesforce-trailhead-lightning-experience-rollout-specialist-superbage/#_top